# Repeating names in /proc/kallsyms

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Why do some symbols in /proc/kallsyms repeat? For eg: I see that `_acpi_module_name`, `__this_module`, `cleanup_module`, `.LC0` repeat multiple times.

Why does this happen? Why are there symbols such that a name resolves to multiple addresses? I see __acpi_module_name repeat 113 times in /proc/kallsyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are different cases.

For `_acpi_module_name`, they are just static global variables. A static global variable or a function is "seen" only in the file it's declared in. It's defined in `include/acpi/acoutput.h`.

```
#define ACPI_MODULE_NAME(name)          static const char ACPI_UNUSED_VAR _acpi_module_name[] = name;
```

For `__this_module`, they are defined in every kernel module, which is added by `script/mod/modpost`.

```
 /**
 * Header for the generated file
 **/
static void add_header(struct buffer *b, struct module *mod)
{
        buf_printf(b, "#include <linux/module.h>\n");
        buf_printf(b, "#include <linux/vermagic.h>\n");
        buf_printf(b, "#include <linux/compiler.h>\n");
        buf_printf(b, "\n");
        buf_printf(b, "MODULE_INFO(vermagic, VERMAGIC_STRING);\n");
        buf_printf(b, "MODULE_INFO(name, KBUILD_MODNAME);\n");
        buf_printf(b, "\n");
        buf_printf(b, "__visible struct module __this_module\n");
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        buf_printf(b, "__attribute__((section(\".gnu.linkonce.this_module\"))) = {\n");
        buf_printf(b, "\t.name = KBUILD_MODNAME,\n");
        if (mod->has_init)
                buf_printf(b, "\t.init = init_module,\n");
        if (mod->has_cleanup)
                buf_printf(b, "#ifdef CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD\n"
                              "\t.exit = cleanup_module,\n"
                              "#endif\n");
        buf_printf(b, "\t.arch = MODULE_ARCH_INIT,\n");
        buf_printf(b, "};\n");
}
```

For `cleanup_module`, it's defined in `include/linux/module.h`

```
#define module_exit(exitfn)                                     \
        static inline exitcall_t __maybe_unused __exittest(void)                \
        { return exitfn; }                                      \
        void cleanup_module(void) __attribute__((alias(#exitfn)));
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

#endif
```

For `.LC0`, it's compiler generated label in different source file like static global variables.