# Linux driver loading - function name resolving at dynamic linking stage

Tags: c, linux, linker, kernel, driver

Let's say I have a Linux driver A, which has a non-static and non-extern function void f(int) declared and defined in driver's .h and .c source code and also gets used in the driver module too; When I load A.ko into the kernel, how is the f(int) resolved in A.ko's usage. Does the linking process first check existing kernel including the loaded driver modules for f(int) first, if not there then the f(int) function's copy in A.ko gets to be linked in and used - If f(int) is found, then the copy in A.ko gets ignored? or something else?

Comment: If there is already a symbol `f` then your driver will have a conflict, otherwise it will add f to the symbol table.  You should name any exported symbol from driver A `A_f` so it won't conflict with other modules.

Comment: r u saying I would not be able to load the A.ko if f(int) is already in the kernel (or a loaded driver)? That seems to be not true with my experience - for example: kallsyms show 2 xdev_find_by_pdev ntries from two driver modules:
     0000000000000000 t xdev_find_by_pdev [qdma_pf_cash3]
     0000000000000000 t xdev_find_by_pdev [qdma_pf]

Comment: Where did I say your driver wouldn't load? Don't make things up.

Comment: @stark clam down, I was not sure you meant by that. Would you please let me know why I would want to resolved the "conflict" then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46889468/1216776